# Problem with Blenders Array Modifier to orbit or place in circular order (blender 3.0)

Tags: arrays, blender, modifier

I was having the problem mentioned above and found that many of the tutorials are mentioning implementing the procedure on the centre of the canvas or world origin.

The question is how to perform that in any location successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with blender the simple answer for you is - keep the **Origins** **at the same place** for both Centre and Orbital objects and make sure to **apply the transforms**.

For others-

1. **Shift + Right-click** to move the 3d Cursor to the desired location.
2. Create the Object that is to be Orbited or rotated.
3. Shape it as desired, then selecting that press **Ctrl + A** and press **All Transforms**,*that will move it's origin to the world Origin,* to correct that In **object mode** select the object and Rightclick then select **Set Origin**. and select the centre of mass to keep it in a visible field. *(You can always edit your object in edit mode that will not destroy your array but minor modification will be required. )* (centring the origin isn't mandatory at this step, described to inform the process)
4. Place the **3d cursor** at the point of the Orbital object from which it should face the centre. (to perform in complex object go to edit mode and select with vertex or edge or face selection and press Shift+S  and select "Cursor to selected")

[image]

5. Having the cursor at desired point Create a cube or anything that will help to visualise the rotation. The cube will be exactly placed on the 3d cursor as well as its origin. Scale it as required. and **apply all transforms** as previous and reposition the origin to the **3D cursor**.

[image]

6. Select the Orbital object and set its origin to the **3d cursor** too.
7. If required provide some spacing to the Orbital object from the centre object (cube).
   *(but it will be helpful to visualize if you do that after creating the array, going to the edit mode of the orbital object)*
8. Selecting the Orbital object assign Array modifier. Provide the desired number of objects under **Count** and make all axis of Relative offset 0 to get all orbital objects in the same plane. (relative offset comes pre-selected)
9. **Tick Object Offset** and with the Dropper select the Cube.

**Now if the array doses strange things like the image below**

[image]

**It means either both of your Center and Orbital objects don't have origin At the same point (here 3d cursor) or You forgot to Apply the transforms for the objects.**

10. Now you can rotate the cube to get the desired arrangement in circular form.

[image]

11. To provide the spacing from the centre object, go to the orbital object and press Tab for edit mode there selecting the original and move it along the upward axis allow you to have spacing. Because moving objects in edit mode don't affect the origin. that is still at the 3d cursor
    Not only spacing you can do various formations rotating, moving the orbital object in edit mode.

[image]

12. Play with relative offset to get various looks.

Answer (score 0):

The videos skim over setting origin and checking and re-checking transforms and origin points. This is a really important step and even following your detailed instructions it took a few tries to get it right.

This circular array modification is really tricky to get, but once learned it is a great tool for speeding up workflow.

Thanks for this

Comment: I am glad to be helpful, please upvote if you think this should come to the attention of other people suffering, next time please add your thoughts in the comments, the answering section is dedicated to possible solutions.